# Triggering a function in a React parent functional component from its child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Seen similar issues here, but couldn't wrap my mind on how this works. New to functional components and React overall.

`Parent` contains the `Child`, which is a modal. Parent has a `div` that triggers showing the `Child` modal, and the `Child` modal has a `close` button that triggers its hiding. When I click on the `div` component in `Parent`, I need to show and hide the `Child` modal. When I click on the `close` button in the `Child`, I need to hide the `Child` component.

The **Parent** component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

const Parent = () => {
  const [buttonState, setbuttonState] = useState({
    buttonState: false,
  });

  const onParentClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setbuttonState(!buttonState);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={onParentClick}></div>
      <Child isOpen={buttonState} onParentClick={onParentClick} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

The **Child** component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Child = (props) => {
  const [buttonState, setButtonState] = useState({
    buttonState: props.isOpen,
  });

  const onChildClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setButtonState(false);
    props.onParentClick();
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={
        buttonState ? "child-modal-opened" : "child-modal-closed"
      }
    >
      <div onClick={onChildClick}>Close</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

For some reason, can't make this work. What am I missing here?

Comment: Looks correct --- pass it as a prop, call that prop from the child, do something in the parent.  Is there any sort of error?  Using Typescript you'll often get an error doing this that "onChildClick" isnt defined because you have to bind the method to `this` but using an FC I don't think you have that problem.  I don't use FC syntax but I think you might still need to refer to it as `state.buttonState` in the Child component's render method.

Comment: I think `useState()` is used incorrectly. Try `const [buttonState, setbuttonState] = useState(false);` in Parent

Comment: You have the button state in both components. I'd leave it in the parent component and pass the `buttonState` and `setButtonState` as props to the child instead of duplicating the state in the child. Edit: Also what @Vitalii said.

Comment: @Will Thanks! Worked. If you want please write your own version, and I'll accept it as a correct answer.

Comment: Vitalli has it down there. Go ahead and accept his. This was a team effort. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [`useState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) is used incorrectly.

```
const [buttonState, setbuttonState] = useState({
    buttonState: false,
  });
```

results in `buttonState` being `{ buttonState: false}`, so `setbuttonState(!buttonState)` does not work as intended.

Here's updated Parent component with `useState(false)` instead (setting initial `buttonState` value to `false`)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

const Parent = () => {
  const [buttonState, setbuttonState] = useState(false);

  const onParentClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setbuttonState(!buttonState);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={onParentClick}></div>
      <Child isOpen={buttonState} onParentClick={onParentClick} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

*P.S.*

As @Will suggested, there is no need to create another state in Child, it can be passed from Parent

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Child = (props) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={
        props.isOpen ? "child-modal-opened" : "child-modal-closed"
      }
    >
      <div onClick={props.onParentClick}>Close</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but the main reason was that I was using the state in the child as well. Removed the state from the child completely only using the parent props and it worked.

Comment: If you need to use a state property from the parent in your child, just pass it to the child as a prop and call it just like in this example. e.g. `props.theStatePropertyFromParent`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like onParentClick is defined so as to take an event object as a parameter and call preventDefault() on that, but you're calling it without any arguments. Does it work like this: `props.onParentClick(e);`?